# runtime error when I extract try-catch

Tags: c++, runtime

All code :  https://pastebin.com/k7TZzQEY

```
/*If i remove try catch runtime error appear.*/ 
try
    {
        SnowAdventure.DodajUplatu(nisvet, trening_1, uplata_1, "trening");
        SnowAdventure.DodajUplatu(nisvet, trening_2, uplata_2, "trening");
        SnowAdventure.DodajUplatu(nisvet, trening_3, uplata_3, "trening");
        SnowAdventure.DodajUplatu(nisvet, trening_1, oprema_nm, "oprema");
        SnowAdventure.DodajUplatu(nisvet, trening_3, oprema_NM, "oprema");

    }
    catch (const std::exception& obj)
    {
        obj.what();

    }
/*Function*/
void DodajUplatu(Ucenik & ucenik, Trening & trening, Uplata & uplata, string svrha) {
        for (int i = 0; i < _treninzi.size(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < _treninzi[i].getUcenici().size(); j++)
            {
                if (*_treninzi[i].getUcenici()[j] == ucenik) {
                    if (svrha == "oprema") {
                        int size = _treninzi[i].getUcenici()[j]->getIznajmljenaOprema()->size();
                        bool uplaceno = false;
                        for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
                        {
                            Oprema * oprema = &(*_treninzi[i].getUcenici()[j]->getIznajmljenaOprema())[k];
                            if (oprema->getCijena() >= uplata.getIznos()) {
                                _treninzi[i].getUcenici()[j]->DodajUplatu(uplata, svrha);
                                uplaceno = true;
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                        if (!uplaceno) {
                            throw exception("Niste uplatili!");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (trening.getTipTreninga() == Pocetnicki) {
                            if (uplata.getIznos() == trening.getBrojCasova() * 10) {
                                _treninzi[i].getUcenici()[j]->DodajUplatu(uplata, svrha);
                                return;
                            }
                            else {
                                throw exception("Niste uplatili dovoljno novca!");
                            }
                        }
                        else if(trening.getTipTreninga()==Rekreativni)
                        {
                            if (uplata.getIznos() == trening.getBrojCasova() * 15) {
                                _treninzi[i].getUcenici()[j]->DodajUplatu(uplata, svrha);
                                return;
                            }
                            else {
                                throw exception("Niste uplatili dovoljno novca!");
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (uplata.getIznos() == trening.getBrojCasova() * 20) {
                                _treninzi[i].getUcenici()[j]->DodajUplatu(uplata, svrha);
                                return;
                            }
                            else {
                                throw exception("Niste uplatili dovoljno novca!");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                throw exception("Nepoznat ucenik koji je zaprimljen kao parametar!");
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Briefly, What error you get?

Comment: abort() has been called

Comment: when i remove try catch block from code,with try catch it works perfectly

Comment: Sounds like you need to print `obj.what();` so that you know what the exception is so you can fix it.  Just doing `catch (const std::exception& obj){ obj.what();  }` throws out thew exception.

Comment: `std::cerr << obj.what() << '\n';` would seem a pretty obvious thing to do. What you have right now seems rather pointless unless the intention was to (a) catch the exception, (b) purposely *avoid* knowing what it was, and (c) throw it out; i.e. ignore it. as you're *throwing* all those exceptions throughout that code, it stands to reason you have interest in knowing what was thrown. So why ignore it?

Answer (score 2):

[cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw) says following:

> Once the exception object is constructed, the control flow works
>   backwards (up the call stack) until it reaches the start of a try
>   block, at which point the parameters of the associated catch blocks
>   are compared with the thrown expression to find a match. If no match
>   is found, the control flow continues to unwind the stack until the
>   next try block, and so on. If a match is found, the control flow jumps
>   to the matching catch block (the exception handler), which executes
>   normally.
>
> As the control flow moves up the call stack, destructors are invoked
>   for all objects with automatic storage duration constructed since the
>   corresponding try-block was entered, in reverse order of construction.
>   If an exception is thrown from a constructor, destructors are called
>   for all fully-constructed non-static non-variant members and base
>   classes. This process is called stack unwinding.

**Explanation**

> abort() has been called when i remove try catch block from code

It means if your code throws an exception (function `DodajUplatu` does), and this exception isnt handled in try/catch block (**it isnt if you remove it**), an `abort()` - Runtime error is called.

> with try catch it works perfectly

Yes because this exception was caught in catch block.

---

You should read about [exceptions](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/) to get extended info.
Or better read some [C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).